# Magento Lost Style after checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Tags: magento

```
        <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <sendmail>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Xkey_Redegrupo_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>sendMailRGroup</method>
                </sendmail>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
```

If I change the checkout_onepage_controller_success_action to sales_order_after_save, work but send 2 times the e-mail, when I use this, the e-mail sends succefull but the layout of /onepage/checkout/success/ lost style ? Why? ! help me Ç.Ç

Answer (score 0):

Kin  checkout_onepage_controller_success_action is an  event is occur after order has successfully place and redirected to c`heckout/onepage/success pages.it an fronted event.sales_order_after_`save is global event and it is run when you save order. `several time are occurs during order procedure....`
Exmple of event

```
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <create_invoice_for_zero_payment>
                        <class>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/createinvoice</class>
                        <method>automaticinovoice</method>
                    </create_invoice_for_zero_payment>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

Comment: When I use salve_order_after_save, the method is called two times when finish de order and if I cancel the order, the method is called again.

Comment: Whenever,magento codes run save() of sales is run then sales_order_after_save run...